# not able to access CSS class for ag-grid in angular 2

Tags: html, css, angular, ag-grid

I am not able to access a predefined class for ag-grid. I don't know where i am getting wrong. Please help.

Below is my html.

```
<div style="width: 800px; padding-left: 100px" class="ag-fresh">
<button (click)="refreshRowData()">Refresh Data</button>
<button (click)="autoFit()">AutoFit</button>
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 1000px; height: 500px;" 
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 enableSorting
                 enableFilter >


</ag-grid-angular>
```

next is my css

```
.ag-header-cell-label {

 text-overflow: clip;
overflow: visible;
white-space: normal; 
background-color: black;
border-bottom-color: green;
border-left-style: dotted;
color: orange;
}
```

my component.ts. In this i have fixed to horizontal scroll.So i want to display data as a single view no scrolling vertically and in this i want to wrap my header name which is not happening.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ GridOptions } from 'ag-grid';

import { FlightGridStatusComponent } from '../flight-grid-status/flight-grid-status.component';
import { FetchedFlightInfoBean } from '../../_model/FetchedFlightInfoBean';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-fer-home-child',
  templateUrl: './fer-home-child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fer-home-child.component.css']
})
export class FerHomeChildComponent  {

    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
private refreshFlag: boolean;
fetchedFltBean: FetchedFlightInfoBean [] = [

{tokenNbr:1, flightNbr:"AY01", flightDate: "12-aug-17", flightBrPoint:"DEL", flightoffPoint:"LKO", nbrPax:2, okEmail:"Y", nonOkEmail:"N", okphn:"Y", nonOkPhn:"N", status:"INPROGRESS"},
{tokenNbr:2, flightNbr:"AY02", flightDate: "6-aug-17", flightBrPoint:"BAN", flightoffPoint:"MUM", nbrPax:4, okEmail:"N", nonOkEmail:"Y", okphn:"Y", nonOkPhn:"N", status:"PROCESSED"},
{tokenNbr:3, flightNbr:"AY013", flightDate: "22-aug-17", flightBrPoint:"HEL", flightoffPoint:"PAR", nbrPax:1, okEmail:"N", nonOkEmail:"Y", okphn:"Y", nonOkPhn:"N", status:"INTERUPTED"}
];


constructor() {

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{headerHeight: 48,
            rowHeight: 35,

            rowSelection: 'single',
            enableColResize: true,
           onGridReady: (params) => {
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();

            }


            };


    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {headerName: 'Token Number', field: 'tokenNbr', },
        {headerName: "Flight Number", field: "flightNbr",},
        {headerName: "Flight Date", field: "flightDate",},
        {headerName: "Flight Boarding Point", field: "flightBrPoint" },
        {headerName: "Flight Off Point", field: "flightoffPoint"},
        {headerName: "NBR of Pax", field: "nbrPax"},
        {headerName: "Ok Email", field: "okEmail"},
        {headerName: "NonOk Email", field: "nonOkEmail"},
        {headerName: "Ok Phone", field: "okphn"},
        {headerName: "NonOk Phone", field: "nonOkPhn"},
        {
            headerName: "Status", 
            field: "status",
            cellRendererFramework: FlightGridStatusComponent,

        }

    ];



     this.gridOptions.rowData = this.createRowData();

}

public refreshRowData()
{
    this.refreshFlag = true;
    alert(`inside refreshRowData`);
    let rowData = this.createRowData();
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(rowData);

}

private createRowData() {


    if(this.refreshFlag)
        {
            alert(`refresh call`);
        }
    let rowData:FetchedFlightInfoBean[] = this.fetchedFltBean;



   /* let rowDataLength = rowData.length;
    alert(`${rowDataLength}`)
   for (var i = 0; i < rowDataLength; i++) {
        rowData.push({
            tokenNbr: 1,
            flightNbr: "",
            flightDate: "",
            flightBrPoint: "",
            flightoffPoint: "",
            nbrPax: 3,
            okEmail: "",
            nonOkEmail: "",
            okphn: "",
            nonOkPhn: "",
            status: "",
        });
    }
*/      

    return rowData;
}


}
```

Comment: Please share your .ts code as well.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-angular-example.

Comment: @EbadMasood i have added the component. Also i have seen this link before also but no help. They all have horizontal scroll which is not an option for me.

Comment: try adding the `!important` tag to your css. One guess is that your custom css is being loaded before ag-grid's css which would mean that ag-grid's css would take precedence

Comment: @JarodMoser not working.